# UIPopoverController: How to move it?

Tags: ios, uiview, uipopovercontroller

I want to move a `UIPopoverController`. The only way I found was calling
[popover presentPopoverFromRect...] with the new position in view.

This actually moves it but doesnt goes exactly where I want, I am using `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny`.

There is any other option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [popover presentPopoverFromRect...] is the correct way to move a UIPopoverController as the Technical Q&A document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1694/_index.html.
If you have an exactly position for your popover, I think you should have an exactly UIPopoverArrowDirection other than using UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny. This may effect to the position of popover.